# Story about a Singaporean company that is contracted to modernize an Indian city?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

As for question title, I am looking for a story about a Singaporean company that is contracted to modernize an Indian city.

The story should be quite short, probably under the average under novel length, maybe a short story or novella. I think it may have been published in [Asimov's Science Fiction magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asimov%27s_Science_Fiction), [Analog Science Fiction and Fact Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_Science_Fiction_and_Fact) or another similar print.

In the story the company is trying to "modernize" the city by taking over the local government function.

I remember a vignette where the on-the-ground company city leader is speaking with a matron in a Singaporean office physically. The matron had experience with many modernisations.

Also there is something about "women are best to promote as they think of the family first and are more likely to pay back loans".

So it's not just local government, it's also got a bit of micro-loan in the story as well like kiva.

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Especially what sci-fi elements were there in the story.

Comment: There's a full-length novel called _The Space Merchants_ that has a hint of this. But I don't think it's what you're looking for, and you're going to have to provide more information about what you remember in order to narrow it down.

Comment: Better now? Any updates?

Comment: Do you recall approximately when you read it?  Past couple of years?  5? 20?

Comment: Around 5 to 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great fit, but Bruce Sterling's [Green Days in Brunei](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41351) might be it.  This is a novella, published in Asimov's in 1985, and is described [here](https://sffremembrance.com/2023/09/24/novella-review-green-days-in-brunei-by-bruce-sterling/).

The hero is Chinese-Canadian (with a grandfather from Hong Kong) working for a Japanese (not Singaporean) company to modernize facilities in Brunei (not India), but I'm allowing for some misremembering over several decades.